# Fix locally copied/added TFS folder so it is a Branch with Ancestry

Tags: tfs, branch, branching-and-merging

1. Copy folders between Team Projects LOCALLY (`e.g. xcopy D:\foo\TeamProjectA\Blah D:\foo\TeamProjectB\Blah`)
2. Add D:\foo\TeamProjectB\Blah to $/TeamProjectB.
3. Make $/TeamProjectA/Blah a Branch - does not have hierarchy.
4. Make $/TeamProjectB/Blah a Branch - does not have hierarchy.

How do I set the parent of TeamProjecB/Blah to TeamProjectA/Blah?

**EDIT ** `2010-12-31`
What about editing the DB directly?

Comment: Editing the database is far from supported, and should be avoided in any cases. The database is not a nice relation database, but a very optimized complex data store. Modifying even the simplest change could have impact on your system, and even make the TFS environment unusable.

Comment: Okay... so the original answer stands. I do NOT like the answer... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not possible. You need to do a [baseless merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd6dxhfy.aspx) if you want to achieve a merge between the two. But the branch relationship cannot be set.

Comment: So there's no Git-like grafts table?